# How to flatten nested hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

What is the quickest way to flatten this hash:

```
REGIONS = {
  :au => {
    'Australian Capital Territory' => 'ACT',
    'New South Wales' => 'NSW',
  },
  :ca => {
    'Alberta' => 'AB',
    'British Columbia' => 'BC',
  }
}
```

so that the `:au` and `:ca` keys are removed and I get:

```
{
  'Australian Capital Territory' => 'ACT',
  'New South Wales' => 'NSW',
  'Alberta' => 'AB',
  'British Columbia' => 'BC'
}
```

I can merge hashes like this:

```
REGIONS[:au].merge(REGIONS[:ca])
```

But I can't do this here because the names of the hash keys will change frequently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
REGIONS.values.reduce(&:merge)
```

Comment: You can omit the `&`.

Comment: @sawa I know but I prefer explicit over implicit. `&` is a core syntax, working everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in a single iteration.

```
REGIONS.inject({}){|h, (_, e)| h.merge(e)}
```